# INSERT INTO #tmp from CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, common-table-expression

I want to be able to insert the results of this CTE query into a temp table so I can sum the Total column.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(50),
    StartDateTime NVARCHAR(50),
    EndDateTime NVARCHAR(50),
    Total NVARCHAR(50)
)

;WITH cte1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE                
           WHEN Temperature > @maxthreshold AND LAG(Temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY CombineDateTime) IS NULL THEN 1               
           WHEN Temperature <= @maxthreshold  AND LEAD(Temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY CombineDateTime) > @maxthreshold THEN 1              
           WHEN Temperature <= @maxthreshold  AND  LAG(Temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY CombineDateTime) > @maxthreshold THEN 1
        END AS chg
    FROM 
        [RawData]
    WHERE 
        SerialNumber = @_Serial
        AND CombineDateTime BETWEEN @_DateFrom AND @_DateTo
), cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        SUM(chg) OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY CombineDateTime) AS grp
    FROM 
        cte1
)
INSERT INTO #tmp
    SELECT
        SerialNumber,
        MIN(CombineDateTime) AS StartDateTime,
        MAX(CombineDateTime) AS EndDateTime,
        DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(CombineDateTime), MAX(CombineDateTime)) / 60.0 AS 'Total'
    FROM 
        cte2
    GROUP BY 
        SerialNumber, grp
    HAVING 
        MAX(Temperature) > @maxthreshold)

SELECT * 
FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

I have tried putting the insert in various places, but it does not insert, I have tried the following answers. I am confused as to why the insert won't work as it is outside of the recursion.

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008316/insert-into-from-cte)
[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28156540/sql-insert-into-using-cte)

TIA

Comment: Try removing the extraneous close parenthesis after`HAVING MAX(Temperature) > @maxthreshold`.

Comment: I did try that and nothing happened.

Comment: Please look at your cte2, in which you are not using group by at all. i guess something is working there as well.

Comment: @balaji Is there a specific reason perhaps why this won't insert